# JQuery keypress event not firing, fiddle and browser dont report errors

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in my page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#txtRequestForecastID').keypress(function (e) {
     var kars = $(this).val();
     if (kars.length() > 0) {
        $('#lblSystemNameCabPos').hide();
        $('#rbSystemNameCabPos').hide();
        $('#txtSystemNameCabPos').hide();
        $('#rvtxtSystemNameCabPos').hide();
     } else {
        $('#lblSystemNameCabPos').show();
        $('#rbSystemNameCabPos').show();
        $('#txtSystemNameCabPos').show();
        $('#rvtxtSystemNameCabPos').show();
     }
  });
});
```

But it is not working.
The event is not firing.
Fiddle doesn't show me any errors, browser doesn't show me any errors.
I can't figure it out.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cWjMF/37/

Please help.

Comment: where is the element with id `txtRequestForecastID`

Comment: ^ What Arun said, and you don't have **any** elements matching any of those ID's ?

Comment: Correct, there is no such element in your fiddle. What did you expect? :)

Comment: By mistake you write id # instead of class . it is mistake in code

Comment: This script is actually build in code behind and it is the clientID of the element. The HTML code in the fiddle is from the page generated by the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake you write id # instead of class . it is mistake in code
try this you will have event now

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.txtSystemIdentifier').keypress(function (e) {
        alert("in");
        var kars = $(this).val();
        if (kars.length() > 0) {
            $('#lblSystemNameCabPos').hide();
            $('#rbSystemNameCabPos').hide();
            $('#txtSystemNameCabPos').hide();
            $('#rvtxtSystemNameCabPos').hide();
        } else {
            $('#lblSystemNameCabPos').show();
            $('#rbSystemNameCabPos').show();
            $('#txtSystemNameCabPos').show();
            $('#rvtxtSystemNameCabPos').show();
        }
    });
});
```